# Create file causes access denied in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, file, permissions, access-denied

I was trying to create function which will create a file in a specific folder. But every time when I am trying to create the file, it will shows me access denied. I have read a lot of solution, but i still have no clue on how to solving the problems.

```
 Dim x as string 
 x = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath)

 Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles APIsaveBtn.Click
    SaveFileDialog1.Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*|CSV Files (*.csv)|*.csv"
    SaveFileDialog1.FileName = ""


    Dim newArray As New ArrayList()
    Dim path As String = x
    If File.Exists(path) = True Then
        System.IO.File.WriteAllText(path, "")

        newArray.Sort()
        My.Settings.API_Path = path
        My.Settings.API_Key = APIkeyTxtBox.Text
        Using sw As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter(path, True)

            sw.WriteLine(APIkeyTxtBox.Text)

        End Using
        apikey = APIkeyTxtBox.Text
        MessageBox.Show("Save Sucessfully", "Save")

   ElseIf File.Exists(path) = False Then
        Dim newFile As IO.StreamWriter = System.IO.File.CreateText(path)
        newFile.Close()
        My.Settings.API_Path = path
        My.Settings.API_Key = APIkeyTxtBox.Text
        Using sw As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter(path, True)

            sw.WriteLine(APIkeyTxtBox.Text)

        End Using
        apikey = APIkeyTxtBox.Text
        MessageBox.Show("Save Sucessfully", "Save")
    End If
```

I have no idea on how to give permission to allow create file a specific folder.

Comment: Your `path` seems to be a directory path, and not a file path.

Comment: @Bob what's the difference between file path and directory path

Comment: `c:\temp` is a directory path. You can create *files in it*, but you cannot use a *stream to write in it*... because you cannot write text in a directory. `c:\temp\myfile.txt` is a file path. You can create a file with this address, or use a stream to write in it.

Comment: @Bob what if i wanted to create a file into C:\temp? is there any ways to do that?

Comment: You necessarily know your file name. So lets suppose you have `path` for your folder (`c:\temp`) and `fileName` for your file (`Myfile.txt`), the full path will be `filePath=System.Io.Path.Combine(path,fileName)` and then you just do `System.IO.File.CreateText(filePath)`.

Comment: @Bob Thanks! that's helps alot